I cannot hide the "Automate" button in SharePoint library commandbar using JSON Formatting

I have tried using the JSON code to hide the "Automate" button from SharePoint list but it has no effect. It works on all other buttons except "Automate". Can some please help?

Seems like issue at Microsoft end, try raising support ticket with Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support

Whether the issue exists? I apply JSON codes now, it works.
